# php range query

Tags: php, smarty, range

Basic question here. I am using php(smarty) range to populate an array for days in the month.

```
$smarty->assign('date', range(1,31 ));
```

The form sends OK, but because counts start at 0, when I pick 20 from dropdown 19 gets sent in the form.

How do I set it so it starts at 1?

Answer (score 1):

The range() function does not allow you to specify the keys for the array.  The simplest option would be to create your own array:

```
$range = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
    $range[$i] = $i;
}
$smarty->assign('date', $range);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$days = array_combine(range(1,31),range(1,31));
```

Or, possibly more efficient, although it's a micro-optimalisation:

```
$range = range(1,31);
$days = array_combine($range,$range);
```